# EC2 , Openstack, Google App Engine (GAE) and REST

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openstack

I was handed an assignment but I don't know where to start.

The aim is to have 2 piece of code running. One will run in Open stack private cloud and perform the task of indexing two sets of text, with another running in EC2 with the task of matching the two indexed tests.

I want to access them via google app engine.

Ideally, I would like to click a button or perform an action on Google app engine, which then sends a request to Openstack to run the code and retrieve the output of a txt file.

That outputted text files will then be forwarded onto EC2 where the matching will occur and the results sent back to Google App Engine.

My question is, how can I send the files between the systems using REST requests?

Answer (score 0):

FrankN --

EC2, GAE and OpenStack are disparate cloud computing platforms. To integrate them might include, say, using one platform while saving backups to another.

CloudU.Rackspace.com is a vendor-neutral education site about cloud computing (note: It'll take six or so hours to finish it all). This might help.

Disclaimer: I work for Rackspace.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, not really sure what your requirements are, why your code does or why are you trying to mix cloud providers in that way.

That said, I would suggest taking the upload from GAE and push it to AWS S3 where you can then retrieve and use as you please from EC2.

Not sure what functionality you are trying to get out of OpenStack that is not present in AWS; however, I would suggest building whatever you are building in EC2 first, then duplicate in on OpenStack services to avoid future vendor lock in.